# How big can variable be, in python?

Tags: python, variables

I get an response in Python program from SQL server. How big can this response be? What is the maximum?  Coult it be as much as about 100 mb?

Comment: What Python database module are you using?

Comment: First i was using pymssql. than odbc. And completly I deside use soap Web service.

Comment: Technicality: note that it's not a “variable”; Python doesn't have any, more or less. You want the maximum size of an object; what you call “variables” are names of objects.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

See `sys.maxsize`: http://docs.python.org/library/sys.html

> The largest positive integer supported by the platform’s Py_ssize_t type, and thus the maximum size lists, strings, dicts, and many other containers can have.

On my MacBook Pro with a 64-bit build of CPython, it's quite sensibly 2<sup>63</sup>-1 bytes:

```
>>> import sys
>>> sys.maxsize
9223372036854775807
>>>
```

While on my 32-bit Linux box, it's 2^<sup>31</sup>-1:

```
>>> import sys
>>> sys.maxsize
2147483647
>>>
```

In practice, of course, you're unlikely to be able to *actually* make use of objects this large, but you can expect to run into serious practical problems (like, say, being out of memory or taking forever to load/save objects from storage) before you hit the theoretical limits.

Answer (score 5):

There's no reason you can't hold 100 MB of data in Python, system memory permitting.  But you should try to use an iterator, rather than reading the whole result set into a list.